# How can I do backPress after scanning a code Zxing

Tags: android, kotlin, onclick, zxing, back

I imported zxing library for qr code scanner but it is not working properly.
Its scanning screen is from zxing library so it doesn't require my own layout xml (It shows its own). I just created a xml because I have to bind it on my fragment.

It has no problem when I scan a qr code, but the problem is when the back button is clicked.
I want it to go back to its previous stack when I click back button on bottom bar, but it shows my own layout screen, which is not even the previous stack. I do not know why it happens.

How can I move to my previous screen when the back button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Here I posted how I solved the problem.
[back button to escape Zxing scanner in MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70735548/back-button-to-escape-zxing-scanner-in-mvvm)